# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.bosco.ivdpshg.AttendanceCollectionActivity cannot be cast to SampleDialogFragmentSampleDialogListener

Tags: java, android

Even though I handled the exception still the app crash happens

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof FragmentActivity) {
            try {
                sampleDialogListener = (SampleDialogListener) context;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException("Containing context must implement SampleDialogListener");
        }
    }
```